# How to batch queue records and execute them in a different thread and wait till it;s over?

Tags: c#, multithreading, pushsharp

I am using push sharp  version PushSharp 4.0.4.

I am using it in a windows application.

I have three main methods

1- BroadCastToAll

2- BrodcatsToIOS

3- BrodcatsToAndriod

I have a button calld send. On the click event of the button. I am calling the

BroadCastToAll function.

```
 private void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    var url = "www.mohammad-jouhari.com"
    var promotion = new Promotion ();
    BroadCastToAll(promotion, url);
 }
```

Here is the BrodcastToAll Function

```
 public void BroadCastToAll(Promotion promotion, string url)
 {
    var deviceCatalogs = GetDeviceCatalog();
    BroadCastToIOS(promotion, url, deviceCatalogs.Where(d => d.OS == "IOS").ToList());
    BroadCastToAndriod(promotion, url, deviceCatalogs.Where(d => d.OS == "Android").ToList());
 }
```

Here is the BrodcastToIOS Function

```
 public void BroadCastToIOS(Promotion promotion, string url, List<DeviceCatalog> deviceCatalogs)
 {
    if (deviceCatalogs.Count == 0)
       return;
       lock (_lock)// Added this lock because there is a potential chance that PushSharp callback execute during registering devices
       {
          QueueAllAppleDevicesForNotification(promotion, url, deviceCatalogs, logsMessage);
       }
 }
```

Here is the BrodcastToAndriod Function

```
 public void BroadCastToAndriod(Promotion promotion, string url, List<DeviceCatalog> deviceCatalogs)
 {
    if (deviceCatalogs.Count == 0)
        return;
        lock (_lock)// Added this lock because there is a potential chance that PushSharp callback execute during registering devices
        {
           QueueAllGcmDevicesForNotification(promotion, url, deviceCatalogs, logsMessage);
        }
 }
```

Here is the  QueueAllAppleDevicesForNotification function

```
  private void QueueAllAppleDevicesForNotification(Promotion promotion, string url, List<DeviceCatalog> deviceCatalogs)
        {
            var apnsServerEnviroment = UseProductionCertificate ? ApnsConfiguration.ApnsServerEnvironment.Production : ApnsConfiguration.ApnsServerEnvironment.Sandbox;
            var fileService = new FileService();
            var filePath = Application.StartupPath+ "/Certifcates/" +  (UseProductionCertificate ? "prod.p12" : "dev.p12");
            var buffer = fileService.GetFileBytes(filePath);
            var config = new ApnsConfiguration(apnsServerEnviroment, buffer, APPLE_CERTIFICATE_PWD);
            apnsServiceBroker = new ApnsServiceBroker(config);
            apnsServiceBroker.OnNotificationFailed += (notification, aggregateEx) => {
                aggregateEx.Handle (ex => {
                    // Log the Resposne
                });

            };
            apnsServiceBroker.OnNotificationSucceeded += (notification) => {
                   // Log The Response 
            };
            apnsServiceBroker.Start();
            foreach (var deviceToken in deviceCatalogs) {
                var title = GetTitle(promotion, deviceToken);
                //title += DateTime.UtcNow.TimeOfDay.ToString();
                var NotificationPayLoadObject = new NotificationPayLoadObjectApple();
                NotificationPayLoadObject.aps.alert = title;
                NotificationPayLoadObject.aps.badge = 0;
                NotificationPayLoadObject.aps.sound = "default";
                NotificationPayLoadObject.url = url;
                var payLoad = JObject.Parse(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(NotificationPayLoadObject));
                apnsServiceBroker.QueueNotification(new ApnsNotification
                {
                    Tag = this,
                    DeviceToken = deviceToken.UniqueID,
                    Payload = payLoad
                });
            }
            var fbs = new FeedbackService(config);
            fbs.FeedbackReceived += (string deviceToken, DateTime timestamp) =>
            {
                // This Token is no longer avaialble in APNS
                new DeviceCatalogService().DeleteExpiredIosDevice(deviceToken);
            };
            fbs.Check();

            apnsServiceBroker.Stop();
        }
```

And here is the QueueAllGcmDevicesForNotification

```
private void QueueAllGcmDevicesForNotification(Promotion promotion, string url, List<DeviceCatalog> deviceCatalogs, )
    {
        var config = new GcmConfiguration(ANDROID_SENDER_ID, ANDROID_SENDER_AUTH_TOKEN, ANDROID_APPLICATION_ID_PACKAGE_NAME);
        gcmServiceBroker = new GcmServiceBroker(config);
        gcmServiceBroker.OnNotificationFailed += (notification, aggregateEx) => {
            aggregateEx.Handle (ex => {
                // Log Response
                return true;
            });
        };

        gcmServiceBroker.OnNotificationSucceeded += (notification) => {
           // Log Response
        };
        var title = GetTitle(shopexPromotion);
        gcmServiceBroker.Start ();
        foreach (var regId in deviceCatalogs) {
            var NotificationPayLoadObject = new NotificationPayLoadObjectAndriod(url, title, "7", promotion.ImageUrl);
            var payLoad = JObject.Parse(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(NotificationPayLoadObject));
            gcmServiceBroker.QueueNotification(new GcmNotification
            {
                RegistrationIds = new List<string> { 
                    regId.UniqueID
                },
                Data = payLoad
            });
        }
        gcmServiceBroker.Stop();

    }
```

Now When I click the send button. The event will start executing.

The BrodcastToAll function will be called. I am calling BrodcastToIOS devices first and then BrodcatsToAndriod.

Is there any way in which I can call BrodcastToIOS and wait until all the devices have been Queued and notification has been pushed by the library and the call back events fired fully then start executing the BrodcastToAndriod Fucntion ?

What lines of code I need to add ?

also Is there any way to batch the number of devices to be Queued ?

For example.

Let us say I have 1000 Devices

500 IOS

500 Andriod

Can I queue 100, 100,100,100,100 for IOS and when it's done

I queue 100,100,100,100,100 for Andriod.

Any Help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The call to `broker.Stop ()` by default will block until all the notifications from the queue have been processed.

Comment: I use it and it is not blocking

Comment: https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp/blob/master/PushSharp.Core/ServiceBroker.cs#L70-L95

It is blocking...

Comment: ok he is using Task.WaitAll (all); Do I need to use it in my code ?

Comment: I am reviving alot of ConnectionError in sending ios notification. I checked this link https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp/issues/672 and i am having a lock statment but I am still getting the error.